# Larave error: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given

Tags: php, laravel

Hi fellow Laravel developers:
The following is the output of dd(session('cart')); :

```
array:2 [▼
  17 => array:14 [▼
    "user_id" => 1
    "nr" => "001"
    "check_id" => 17
    "kommission" => "Ribnev Prömski"
    "quantity" => 1
    "price" => "72.95"
    "shipping_cost_id" => 28
 
  ]
  18 => array:14 [▼
    "user_id" => 1
    "nr" => "002"
    "check_id" => 17
    "kommission" => "Ribnev Prömski"
    "quantity" => 1
    "price" => "78.95" 
    "shipping_cost_id" => 28
 
  ]
]
```

Later on id like to save the cart as single rows in the orders table.
In preparation of this ...
When i do the following:

```
foreach (session('cart') as $id => $data ) {
    dump($data['nr']);
}
```

The Browser shows (very short) the first iteration of the foreach "001" ($data['nr']), and then
I get this Error:

> `array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given`.

My Question: What is meant by parameter 2?

Comment: array_merge(parameter 1, parameter 2) ... the value to the 2nd parameter is being given a string somewhere instead of an array.

Comment: In a more verbose version of @PaulT. comment, parameters to functions are the values between the commas when calling the function. Where is the `array_merge` code?

Comment: But why you getting `array_merge()` here, are you sure this line `dump($data['nr']);` throw this error?

Comment: @user3783243 seems to be a laravel built in:

Comment: \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Factory.php
    }
 
    public function make($view, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
    {
        $path = $this->finder->find(
            $view = $this->normalizeName($view)
        );

Comment: Have you read the entire stack trace to find out where it originates from? The file and line displayed in the error are from the deepest level. What's at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by this:

```
$data = collect(session('cart'))->map(function ($item, $key) {
           return $item['nr'];
        });
```

Another way:

You can use pluck the key you want:

```
$collection = collect(session('cart'));

$data = $collection->pluck('nr')
       ->all();
```

More information with collection you can check it at here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections